# How to use GMail API to create drafts without user interaction

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I have a C# program running on an unattended, headless server.

I need the program to be able to send email and create draft emails in my GMail account.

So I need a permanent key or authorisation token for the program to use to access my GMail account.

I keep seeing hints in the huge mountain of GMail API documentation that this is possible, but I can't find any actual instructions on how to create such a key or token.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I eventually found the instructions at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

You create a service account, give it domain wide authority for the appropriate scope (see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), and download a private key in a json file (I called mine `server_credentials.json`).

Then, in your program, you do something like:

```
GmailService getService() {

    GoogleCredential credential;

    try {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"server_credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                .CreateScoped(GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose)
                .CreateWithUser("me@example.com");
        }
        return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "Jumbo Accounts" });
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error logging into Google Mail", ex);
    }
}
```

---

### Additional references:

Gmail API has a list of sample [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/quickstarts-overview?hl=en) references which can guide you how to enable the API, create credentials and even a sample code depending on your preferred programming language. For example: [.NET quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet?hl=en), [Create a project and enable the API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project) and [Create credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials)

Comment: Mind adding some information about how you set up domain wide delegation to the service account.